# forcats and set other level to NA

Tags: r, tidyverse, forcats

I was trying to lump a lot of small category levels to `NA` using `forcats` and `fct_lump`.

```
> h <- forcats::fct_lump_min(factor(mtcars$gear),min = 7,other_level = NA)
> is.na(h)
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[23] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
> table(h,useNA = "always")
h
   3    4 <NA> 
  15   12    5 
> is.na(h)
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[23] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
> table(h,useNA = "ifany")
h
   3    4 <NA> 
  15   12    5
```

From `table(h,useNA="ifany")` I get the impression that NA has been properly assigned, but `is.na(h)` refutes this.

Is it possible to use the convenient `fct_lump` to assign `NA` to the other levels somehow?

Comment: You have a factor with an `NA` level name. Take a look at `is.na(levels(h))`.The observations themselves are not `NA`. Those 5 observations are still stored as factors, look at `as.numeric(h)`, which will show those values are the 3rd factor level.

Comment: Thx-any way of assigning ‘proper’ NA with fct_lump? Or would I have to do that separately?